# Ensure text remains visible during webfont load

Tags: css, angular, fonts, lighthouse

I m using typeface-exo font in Angular.

```css
*{
 font-family: Exo;
 }
```

[image]

Someone help me to resolve this issue. I m facing this for more than 4 days.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55438023/how-to-fix-ensure-text-remains-visible-during-webfont-load help you?

Comment: I have already added &display=swap. but it didn't resolved

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/a/55677584/7265862?